# Memory error in np.hstack()

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to execute this code:

```
for i in Fil:  
    for k in DatArr:  
        a = np.zeros(0)  
        for j in Bui:  
            a = np.hstack([a,DatDifCor[k][i,j]])  
        DatDifPlt[k].update({i:a})
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<ipython console>", line 5, in <module>  
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 258, in hstack  
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_1d,tup),1)  
MemoryError
```

I thought it was due to a lack of RAM memory in the first place, but then I tried in on a PC with 48 Gb of RAM and it gave the same error. Have I reached the maximum size for a NumPy.array?

Comment: 64 Bit operating system?

Comment: i run it on a windows 64 bit os, but python seems not to cope with this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MemoryError` always means that an attempt to allocate memory failed.  Trying to create an array bigger than the maximum array size results in a `ValueError`:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(500000000)
>>> numpy.hstack((a, a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 258, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_1d,tup),1)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Note that 48 GB are also a finite ammount of memory, and that your operating system (or even the hardware platform) might restrict the size of a single process to 4 GB.

Comment: @Sven: The Python process i run increases the RAM usage from 5.85 GB (used by different Modelica simulations) to 7.40 GB (out of 48 GB) whereafter i get the MemoryError, which means the process uses 'only' 1.55 GB ...

Comment: @rubae: This doesn't outrule that you are running out of memory.  If the process uses 1.55 GB and tries to allocate 3 GB, you'll get a `MemoryError` if processes are limited to 4 GB.  I suggest to add some debug output to the loop that shows the size of the array `hstack()` is going to create.

Comment: @Sven: ah, i just found out that i am using a 32bit version of Python(x,y) / Spyder on a 64bit computer, maybe the problem is solves by installing the 64bit version ...

Comment: @Sven: do you know a proper way t ofind out how much memory is exactly required in e.g. this process in the loop with hstack() ? Apparantly there is no decent 64 bit version for Python(x,y), for Numpy, etcetera. (?)

Comment: @rubae: The new array created by your `hstack()` call will occupy `a.nbytes + DatDifCor[k][i,j].nbytes` bytes, provided both the objects you stack are NumPy arrays of the same dtype.  The old array `a` will only be freed after the new one is created.

Comment: @Sven: strangely, the MemoryError is raised after about one 5th of the for loop after 52 140 016 bytes, or only 52 MB, while even on my normal laptop there is still 2.1 out of 4 GB left free ... Bút, this is exactly the moment where the Spyder / Python process reaches 1 GB.

Comment: @rubae: Can you reproduce the issue from an interactive console inside Spyder?  For example, entering `a = [numpy.zeros(8192) for i in range(16384)]` should create a list of NumPy arrays occupying a total of about 1 GB.  It works without any problems in Spyder on my Linux box with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: this gives indeed a usage of 1 097 836 K, if i then want to do something else (e.g. make another list, 10 times smaller) i get the same MemoryError ... whereas makeing the same list `a` twice as long as depicted, i don't get a MemoryError.

Comment: @rubae: I did some experiments, and I can arbitrarily allocate further arrays, up to the point where my process really gets to big.  So in my environment, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sven: what is "really too big" in your case ?

Comment: @rubae: I can come close to a process size of 3 GB, which is the process size limit of the Linux kernel I'm currently running.  Allocations that would lift me above the limit raise a `MemoryError` as expected.

Comment: @Sven: ok, then trying something completely different (maybe i shut put this in another question), can i round a number like 36943695,123456 to use always scientifcally e.g. 3 numbers, i.e. 3.69e7 in order to use much less memory ?

Comment: @rubae: The smallest floating-point number format available is ["single precision"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).  It will use 32 bits per number, half the amount the standard double precision numbers use, and corresponds to about 8 decimal places.  In NumPy, use `dtype=numpy.float32` to use single precision.